# HL Fabric - fabric install *without* fabric-samples?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Bump -- *anyone*???

Is there any documentation for mac / linux that *clearly* describes how to install fabric and fabric-ca *without* having to install fabric-samples?

IOW, something that describes *exactly*:

-- what preqs are needed;

-- where it *has* to be installed (that pesky gopath issue);

-- what directory structures need to be in place for orgs, chaincode, etc.;

-- what needs to be built / made and how

in order to install a fresh fabric so one can build a POC but without all the fabric-samples,   BYFN, first-network baggage? Please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `-d -s` in the curl statement which fabric documentation has for installing fabric images and samples

- `-s` by-passes fabric samples
- `-d` by-passes docker images

Its better just to use `-s`

statement would be like

```
curl -sSL link -s -- -d -s
```